# remove the hightlight from the Telerik RadTreeView on mouse over of it

Tags: c#, wpf, highlight, radtreeview

How to remove the highlight from the Telerik RadTreeView in wpf on mouseover of the RadTreeView. I have used the grid to embed the RadTreeView.(Blue colored highlight should be removed)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnkrR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the style of the `RadTreeViewItem`

```
<Style TargetType="RadTreeViewItem">
  <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFF"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="#000"/>
 </Style.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, but  If i add this style the treeView will not load at all.